# Executing a Python file from Codeigniter

Tags: php, python, codeigniter, command-line, raspberry-pi2

I have some trouble to execute a Python file from a Codeigniter controller's function.

~/application/controllers/Lights.php :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
class Lights extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
        $this->load->helper ( array ('url', 'form') );
    }
    public function turnOn() {
        system('sudo python test.py > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
    }
}
```

but when I try to execute a system call, like :

```
system("sudo gpio mode 15 out");
```

this works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the **full path** to `python` binary and `script`, i.e.:

```
system('/full/path/to/python /full/path/to/test.py > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

If the `python` binary is already on the `PATH` of your apache user (`apache`/`www-user`), you may ignore the full path.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution :)

Comment: The only additional remark I'd make here is that some PHP environments don't mirror the `PATH` configured in a standard user account. They'll run under something like `www-user`, which will have a much more minimal path configured.

Comment: Based on my experience, `python` is already on the `PATH` of the `apache` user, although, I've updated my answer mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

yes I has a problem like that and Thank you for Pedro Lobito answer.
There need a full path to call python file from CI from the root folder.

such as

```
system('sudo -u root -S python /var/www/4led/turnon1.py');
```

*sudo -u root -S  is a command for using root permission with no root password required :D