# Can you execute a Python script from a function in a codeigniter controller

Tags: python, php, codeigniter, scripting

I have a python script that I want to execute from my codeigniter controller.
I found a similar question but wasn't quite able to see the out put ([Executing a Python file from Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093408/executing-a-python-file-from-codeigniter))

Is there a way that I can run a python script from my CI appliation and get the output into a variable or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a python script from php for example with the passthru function.

```
<?php
ob_start();
passthru('/full/path/to/python /full/path/to/test.py arg1 arg2');
$output = ob_get_clean(); 

echo $output;
?>
```

Or with the "system" function.

```
<?php
system('full/path/to/python /full/path/to/test.py', $return_value);
echo $return_value;
?>
```

But your python script should return something if you want to "see" someting.

```
import sys
 #calculate stuff
sys.stdout.write('Bugs: 5 |Other: 10\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Jakob. "return something" is a print statement good enough ?

Comment: If you use "system" in php and "print" in python the "system" function will echo / print it in your php script.